# Button won't open new activity

Tags: java, android

So im trying to make my buttons open new activities within my navigation drawer fragments but something broke in my MainActivity.java

my MainActivity.java....

```
   package east.myapplication;


   import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
   import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
   import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
   import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
   import android.view.MenuItem;

   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
   Toolbar toolbar;
   ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
   android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
   NavigationView navigationView;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout,    toolbar, R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close);

    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener((actionBarDrawerToggle));

    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_container,new HomeFragment());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home Fragment...");
    navigationView = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new     NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId())
            {
                case R.id.home_id:
                    fragmentTransaction =   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new   HomeFragment());
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home Fragment");
                    item.setChecked(true);
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    break;

                case R.id.id_rewards:
                    fragmentTransaction =   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new  RewardsFragment());
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Rewards");
                    item.setChecked(true);
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    break;

                case R.id.id_settings:
                    fragmentTransaction =   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new   SettingsFragment());
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Settings Fragment");
                    item.setChecked(true);
                    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    break;
            }



            return true;
        }
    });

}


    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

}
```

and my rewardsfragment...

```
    package east.myapplication;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;


    public class RewardsFragment extends Activity {

    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_rewards);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    Button anotherButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Button anotherButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    Button anotherButton3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    Button anotherButton4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    Button anotherButton5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(RewardsFragment.this, AmazonActivity.class);
            RewardsFragment.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

     /* new button to open a new activity */
    anotherButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // creating the intent
            Intent intent = new Intent(RewardsFragment.this, CVSActivity.class);
            // starting activity with the created intent
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

     /* new button to open a new activity */
    anotherButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // creating the intent
            Intent intent = new Intent(RewardsFragment.this, SephoraActivity.class);
            // starting activity with the created intent
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

     /* new button to open a new activity */
    anotherButton3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // creating the intent
            Intent intent = new Intent(RewardsFragment.this,    PlayStationActivity.class);
            // starting activity with the created intent
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

     /* new button to open a new activity */
    anotherButton4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // creating the intent
            Intent intent = new Intent(RewardsFragment.this,    AMCActivity.class);
            // starting activity with the created intent
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

     /* new button to open a new activity */
    anotherButton5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // creating the intent
            Intent intent = new Intent(RewardsFragment.this,             BKActivity.class);
            // starting activity with the created intent
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

}

The problem is `fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new RewardsFragment());` it has a red underline under `RewardsFragment` and i dont know how to fix it

I tried everything and this is what I have so far..

```
    package east.myapplication;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;


    public class RewardsFragment extends Fragment {

    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_rewards);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    Button anotherButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Button anotherButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    Button anotherButton3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    Button anotherButton4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
    Button anotherButton5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(RewardsFragment.this, AmazonActivity.class);
            RewardsFragment.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

 /* new button to open a new activity */
    anotherButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // creating the intent
            Intent intent = new Intent(RewardsFragment.this, CVSActivity.class);
            // starting activity with the created intent
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

 /* new button to open a new activity */
    anotherButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // creating the intent
            Intent intent = new Intent(RewardsFragment.this, SephoraActivity.class);
            // starting activity with the created intent
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

 /* new button to open a new activity */
    anotherButton3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // creating the intent
            Intent intent = new Intent(RewardsFragment.this,    PlayStationActivity.class);
            // starting activity with the created intent
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

 /* new button to open a new activity */
    anotherButton4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // creating the intent
            Intent intent = new Intent(RewardsFragment.this,    AMCActivity.class);
            // starting activity with the created intent
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

 /* new button to open a new activity */
    anotherButton5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // creating the intent
            Intent intent = new Intent(RewardsFragment.this,    BKActivity.class);
            // starting activity with the created intent
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });}
```

}

My setContentView is bright red, my findViewByID is red, and lastly (RewardsFragment.this, AmazonActivity.class); is red along with all my other .class's

Here is my bugs

Error:(25, 9) error: cannot find symbol method setContentView(int)

Error:(26, 34) error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)

Error:(27, 41) error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)

Error:(28, 42) error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)

Error:(29, 42) error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)

Error:(30, 42) error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)

Error:(31, 42) error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)

Error:(34, 33) error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(RewardsFragment,Class)
constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; RewardsFragment cannot be converted to String)
constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; RewardsFragment cannot be converted to Context)

Error:(43, 33) error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(RewardsFragment,Class)
constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; RewardsFragment cannot be converted to String)
constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; RewardsFragment cannot be converted to Context)

Error:(53, 33) error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(RewardsFragment,Class)
constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; RewardsFragment cannot be converted to String)
constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; RewardsFragment cannot be converted to Context)

Error:(63, 33) error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(RewardsFragment,Class)
constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; RewardsFragment cannot be converted to String)
constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; RewardsFragment cannot be converted to Context)

Error:(73, 33) error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(RewardsFragment,Class)
constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; RewardsFragment cannot be converted to String)
constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; RewardsFragment cannot be converted to Context)

Error:(83, 33) error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(RewardsFragment,Class)
constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; RewardsFragment cannot be converted to String)
constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; RewardsFragment cannot be converted to Context)

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Comment: can you post your log

Comment: The object you have passed in replace() must be object of Fragment type as I have studied in Tutorial. Please print the suggestion or Log in detail      http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must

```
RewardsFragment extend Fragment 

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

And

```
anotherButton3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // creating the intent
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity,    PlayStationActivity.class);
        // starting activity with the created intent
        getActivity.startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Replace

```
 case R.id.home_id:
                fragmentTransaction =   getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_container, new   HomeFragment());
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home Fragment");
                item.setChecked(true);
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                break;
```

To

```
 FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    manager.beginTransaction()
            .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
            .replace(R.id.content_main, new HomeFragment())
            .commit();
```

This is example extend Fragment

```
public class SettingFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
private TextView mTextTest;
 private TextView mTextTest1;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_setting, container, false);
    addControl(view);

    return view;
}



private void addControl(View view) {
    mTextTest = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_test);
mTextTest1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text_test_1);
    mTextTest.setOnClickListener(this);
  mTextTest1.setOnClickListener(this);

}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    FragmentManager manager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.text_test:
            manager.beginTransaction()
                    .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                    .replace(R.id.content_main, new YourFragment())
                    .commit();
            break;
   case R.id.text_test_1:
  startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), YourActivity.class))
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

Comment: Why switch my Home Fragment though?

Comment: it is example !. You can replace HomeFragment to YourFragment()

Comment: your issue is must "  YourFragment extend Fragment " And 

R.id.main_container is  " id " of FrameLayout

Comment: I posted an update on what is wrong with the code, every time i try to fix it, another error occurs

Comment: @Things BA I posted it, 14 errors. mainly on Error:(26, 34) error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int) on all findViewById's  and Error:(34, 33) error: no suitable constructor found for Intent(RewardsFragment,Class<AmazonActivity>)
constructor Intent.Intent(String,Uri) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; RewardsFragment cannot be converted to String)
constructor Intent.Intent(Context,Class<?>) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; RewardsFragment cannot be converted to Context) those

Comment: Yes I have, public class RewardsFragment extends Fragment {

Comment: I see it, I just dont see how it goes with my buttons?

Comment: change your button to my button_test.

Comment: when you extend Fragment. You must use OnCreateView. Not use OnCreate.

Comment: this is example: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/app/fragment/android-fragments-example/

Comment: yeah but i want to open new activities not colors

Comment: startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), YourActivity.class))

Comment: do you have skype?

Comment: spyke: jackyhieu1211

Comment: The only problem im facing is findViewByID

Comment: public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_setting, container, false);
    Button button1 = (Button) view.findviewById(R.id.button1);
    return view;
}

Comment: Button button1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1)

Answer (score 2):

```
public class RewardsFragment extends Activity
```

Your "Fragment" actually is an Activity.

Change this to extend Fragment and add a blank public constructor, i.e.

```
public class RewardsFragment extends Fragment {

    public RewardsFragment(){
    //Default blank constructor 
    }

    //The rest of your code here

}
```

*On a completely off note, you should [really consider using Butterknife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) for @Bind and @Onclick instead of so many findViewByIds and click listeners in your code. It will help start to clean it up.*

Comment: After, RewardsFragment{ there is an error saying Identifier expected?

Comment: Sorry I typed the code wrong, it should be public RewardsFragment(){ }. I will update the answer.

Comment: @ErickBachhuber after the last }, there is another error saying 'class' or 'interface' expected

Comment: You probably just have one too many ending curly braces. Delete the unused }

Comment: Could you show me an example of the butterknife bind?

Comment: This tutorial should be enough to get you started: http://www.sitepoint.com/tidying-code-with-android-butterknife/